# Problem with ScrollViewer in WPF

Tags: wpf, scrollviewer

I am having a problem with the scrollviewer on my WPF, where the scrollviewer doesn't allow me to scroll right to the bottom of the page, but only scrolls up or down to a given height. How do you make the scrollviewer in WPF scroll the whole page in a given visible screen area?

Comment: Can you post your xaml? That'll be really useful for helping you out. Thanks!

Comment: I don't have it on me because it is at work. Will post relevant snippet tomorrow morning

Answer (score 0):

Simply answering your "how do you make it scroll the whole page?":

```
<ScrollViewer>
    <!-- your content -->
</ScrollViewer>
```

Honest, there's no extra needed.

Here's a complete sample:

```
<Page Width="200" Height="200" Background="Yellow"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
  <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
        HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
    <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
      The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
      <LineBreak/>
      The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
      <LineBreak/>
      The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
      <LineBreak/>
      The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
      <LineBreak/>
      The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
      <LineBreak/>
      The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
      <LineBreak/>
      The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
      <LineBreak/>
      The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
      <LineBreak/>
      The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
      <LineBreak/>
      The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
      <LineBreak/>
      The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
      <LineBreak/>
      The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
      <LineBreak/>
      The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
      <LineBreak/>
      The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
      <LineBreak/>
      The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
      <LineBreak/>
      The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
    </TextBlock>
  </ScrollViewer>
</Page>
```

[image]

Comment: This didn't work. The scrollbar still didn't give the option to reach the about of the page. The snippet of code is <Window width="1260" SizeToContent="Width" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"><ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" CanContentScroll="True" Width="1255" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"></ScrollViewer></Window>

Comment: I see your comment, @Andy5, so I updated my answer with a complete example. I promise it works. I just tested it in Kaxaml.

Comment: Sometimes, @Andy5, when I have trouble like what you are describing, I wrap things in a <Grid/> for some reason that control has the most success taking up all available space.